# Rails Google Maps API V3

Tags: google-maps-api-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to use Google Maps API in Rails 4, Ruby 2 project without any gem. My code is as follows, I can't get Google Maps displayed. The screen is blank, and there isn't any error on the console.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Maps</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
<script>
var map;
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
      mapOptions);
}


$(document).ready(function(){
    initialize();
});
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <%= yield %>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

My Index.html.erb

```
<div id="panel">
      <button onclick="toggleHeatmap()">Toggle Heatmap</button>
      <button onclick="changeGradient()">Change gradient</button>
      <button onclick="changeRadius()">Change radius</button>
      <button onclick="changeOpacity()">Change opacity</button>
</div>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

Comment: Most common reason for a google.map not to show is forgetting to give the canvas some height and width. Besides, it would appear that you don't have a DOM element with `id="map-canvas"`.

Answer (score 0):

As already indicated by Beetroot-Beetroot you need to specify the height at least:

```
<div id="map-canvas" style="height:600px"></div>
```

I tested this on my system and it works like a charm ;-)

Best, 
Ben.